# Solution to $x = \frac{(1-F\left(x\right))}{f(x)}$ with gaussian random var

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I want to find the solution to:
$x = (1-F(x))/f(x)$    where $F()$ is the distribution and $f()$ the density of a gaussian random variable.
Notice that it is also equivalent to solving $x = 1/h(x)$ where $h()$ is the hazard function.

In other words (in the gaussian case), I want to find the solution to:
$x = \frac{\Phi(-(x-\mu)/\sigma)}{\frac{1}{\sigma}\phi((x-\mu)/\sigma)} $
My **first question** would be: is there **any closed form solution**?

I supposed there was no closed form solution to it, so I just solved it numerically. However it seems like I found a weird property:
if $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ (with distrib F and density f) and $Y = aX \sim N(a\mu, a\sigma)$ (with distrib $F_a$ and density $f_a$), then what happens numerically is that I get a **linear relationship** if I plot the solution $x^*$ with respect to $a$.

More precisely it would seem that $x^{**}$ solution to $x^{**} = (1-F_a(x^{**}))/f_a(x^{**})$ is actually equal to: 
**$x^{**} = a x^*$** (where $x^*$ is solution to $x^* = (1-F(x^*))/f(x^*)$.

i.e., if we write $x^* \equiv c(\mu, \sigma)$ (where $c$ stands for constant), then $x^{**} \equiv c(a \mu, a \sigma) = a \ c(\mu, \sigma)$.

What I was wondering is **(i) whether or not it is true** (seems to be numerically but we never know), **(ii) if so, how to prove it**? (so far I'm only able to show that if the solution is linear, then indeed it is consistently linear via the equation, but it's completely tautological).
Ideally I would like to be able to **determine a closed form solution** to $x = (1-F(x))/f(x)$ in the gaussian case but I don't think it's possible.

Notice that this linearity property seems to also hold for **lognormal distributions**. (in which case $Y = aX \sim LN(\mu + log(a), \sigma)$ if $X \sim LN(\mu, \sigma)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x^*$ satisfy the equation

$$ x^* = \frac {\displaystyle \Phi\left(-\frac {x^*-\mu} {\sigma}\right)} {\displaystyle \frac {1} {\sigma}\phi\left(\frac {x^*-\mu} {\sigma}\right)} = \frac {1} {h(x^*;\mu,\sigma)}$$

Then we also have
$$ ax^* = \frac {\displaystyle \Phi\left(-\frac {(ax^*)-(a\mu)} {(a\sigma)}\right)} {\displaystyle \frac {1} {(a\sigma)}\phi\left(\frac {(ax^*)-(a\mu)} {(a\sigma)}\right)} = \frac {1} {h(ax^*;a\mu, a\sigma)}$$

So the result is not surprising.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I had (though did not thought this was sufficient "proof" I don't know why). Am I correct when I say there's no way to find a closed form solution for $x^*$? 
By the way, the property seems to hold for the lognormal case as I mentioned, in which case it is slightly harder to write it down this way (the rescaling only affect $\mu$, which implies that you cannot easily factorize the $a$ (or more precisely the $-ln(a)$) in the $\Phi$ function...
EDIT: nevermind, it's working perfectly for the lognormal case too!

Comment: Indeed in the lognormal case, we will have:  
$ax^* = \Phi\left(\frac{-(ln(ax^*) - ln(a) - \mu)}{\sigma}\right) \ / \  \frac{1}{a\sigma x} \phi\left(\frac{(ln(ax^*) - ln(a) - \mu}{\sigma}\right) = 1/h\left(ax^*, \mu + ln(a), \sigma\right)$      

Which is to be expected since if $X \sim LN(\mu, \sigma)$ then $Y = aX \sim LN(\mu + ln(a), \sigma)$